React Native error: Unimplemented component <RNCSafeAreaProvider> on tos
we are creating a react native tvos project following this repo https://github.com/react-native-tvos/react-native-tvos.
On android we are adding +newArchEnabled=false as oer the repo and we are able ro run the project and produce aok.
On mac we are trying to run the app on simulator but we are getting a red screen check screenshot
